# Extjs 3.2 : Js error in built function "onDocumentReady"

Tags: internet-explorer-10, extjs3

I`m getting js error, after loading below function,

```
  Ext.onReady(function(){
        aFunc123([{header:'ss',Fn:'aFunc1(1)'}],"",undefined,{showCheck:true})
        })
        After coming out of "aFunc123" function,extjs immediatly calls "onDocumentReady" function, problem is, passed arguments are undefined,and also I dont know how it`s getting called.Please check out, for this problem I`m getting error like `"Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference"`.
```

Please suggest me what wrong I`m doing here.

I`m using ExtJS 3.2,IE10.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ext 3.4.1a was released recently to add IE10 support. You can download it from the Ext website. Otherwise, older versions don't have support for IE10.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What should be done for that? Which all files needs to be copied.?